# pywinauto: how to use the memory location string given by wrapper_object()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

I found that in the [docs](http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

> Actual window lookup is performed by wrapper_object() method. It
>   returns some wrapper for the real existing window/control or raises
>   ElementNotFoundError. This wrapper can deal with the window/control by
>   sending actions or retrieving data.

```
>>> dlg_spec.wrapper_object()
<pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.DialogWrapper object at 0x05639B70>
```

<s>What is  `0x05639B70`?</s> And how can I use for instance to print what it contains? (ex: `print(0x05639B70)` )

**[edit]** Since it's actually the memory location (address) of the object (thanks to Juan for that) can I click on it? How?

Comment: `0x05639B70` is not a hash, is the memory location (address) of the object

Comment: @JuanT thanks you, it's a part of what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can list all available methods of the object because it's Python:

```
print(dir(dlg_spec.wrapper_object()))
```

Some controls may have method `.invoke()` because sometimes its meaning is different than just a click. So we left it as `.invoke()`.

For retrieving control's text ("Name" property in Inspect.exe):

```
print(dlg_spec.window_text())
```

Yes, default printing could be improved with a text instead of an address. Added [issue #322](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/322) to remember this.

Comment: thanks (again!) I wish I knew that before. It's great but I still don't understand how I could use the given memory location string. Could you please provide few examples of code using the (0x05639B70). If (0x05639B70) is the memory object of an item in a ListView using print(ditto.ditto.SysListView321.GetItem(3)) . How can I do something that would like `.click(0x05639B70)` or `.0x05639B70.select()` ?

Comment: You definitely don't need to use this memory address. It's internal info about Python object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vasily. I'm even more confuse about those memory location.

Comment: Just ignore it. :) It can be used just to determine any 2 Python objects are the same or just similar. Read about operator "is" and how it differs from "==" if you're so interested. :) But better ignore it.